# Date time matching using regex

Tags: python, regex, string, datetime

I have date time string t1

```
'Sat 02 May 2015 19:54:36 +0530'
```

I want to extract the remove the first and last word, i.e. Sat and +0530. Here is the behavior of the three regex I wrote:

```
(1) re.search(r'(\d{2})([^:]+)([:\d{2}]+)',t1) matches '02 May 2015 19:54:36'
(2) re.search(r'(\d{2})([^:]+)([:\d{2}]{2})',t1) matches '02 May 2015 19:5'
(3) re.search(r'(\d{2})(.+)([\:\d{2}])',t1) matches '02 May 2015 19:54:36 +0530'
```

Can someone explain what's the problem with number 2 and number 3? I thought all of these should yield the same result.

Comment: Why not just parse it to a Date object and then format the Date object?

Comment: @J.N. Could you please show me an example? I am new to Python. Thank you.

Comment: Assuming that you're using Python 2:

Here is how to parse the strings as DateTime objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

And here is how to format the DateTime objects: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Parsing the date and times represented to DateTime objects is way easier than creating relatively fragile regular expressions.

Comment: @J.N. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone explain what's the problem with number 2 and number 3?

The problem in your regex `(\d{2})([^:]+)([:\d{2}]{2})` you are using character class in third group i.e `([:\d{2}]{2})` which means it will match either of these characters `:`, `digits`, `{` ,`2`, `}` twice. Hence it matches `:5` and stops. Same is with third one.

Your first regex `(\d{2})([^:]+)([:\d{2}]+)` because you have used `+` (more than one) quantifier which consumes `:54:36` since they are in character class `[:\d{2}]`.

Removing the character class your second regex will be `(\d{2})([^:]+)(:\d{2}){2}` which will work just fine.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tW16ll/1/)**

Comment: Thank you. Seems like I forgot the purpose of [] for a while :).

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question relates to regex, but it seems that your question is really about how to remove the first and last word from a date string. In your case, I personally would not use regex. Instead you could simply split the string on spaces, and join the resultant list, leaving out the first and last element:

```
In [1]: s = 'Sat 02 May 2015 19:54:36 +0530'

In [2]: ' '.join(s.split(' ')[1:-1])
Out[2]: '02 May 2015 19:54:36'
```

`[1:-1]` will give you all elements of a sequence (in this case a list of strings created by [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split)) from the second element, up to (but not including) the last element.

Regex is not the "wrong" way to solve your problem, and mine is not "right". However, I find that, where applicable, string methods are often better suited for this kind of job, are easier to read, and are less error-prone. That has been my experience at least.

Comment: Thank you. I was just trying to use regex for this problem.

Comment: @Sumit got it! I just wanted to put this out there just in case it was useful for you. I remember when I first learned regex, I was in awe of their power and wanted to use them for everything. In my case it took me a while before I even knew that there were other ways to do things, haha!

Comment: That's funny. Agree, regex is super powerful.